# Does Release Management 2013 rollback across tags

Tags: rollback, ms-release-management

We're heavy users of tags and I'm confused how tags and rollbacks interact together.

I understand that rollbacks cascade (at least within a sequence) from this article:

http://incyclesoftware.com/2014/03/understanding-rollbacks-release-management/

But I'm not clear how this would interact when you use tags, i.e. we tag servers by what features are installed on them (web, database, service) and vary the mix of features depending on environment (i.e. DEV might have web & services running on the same machine, but UAT & PROD would have seperate machines)

So does the rollback go back across the tag boundaries? If for example your sequence looked like this

```
+--Database tag --+
|  Backup DB      |
|      |          |
|  Update DB      |
|      |          |    <- Runs against SQL server
| +--Rollback--+  |
| | Restore DB |  |
| +------------+  |
+-----------------+
         |
+---Web Tag-------+
|   Do Stuff      |    <- Runs against WEB server
+-----------------+
         |
+---Service tag----+
|    Backup        |
|       |          |
| Install new ver  |  <- Runs against Service server
|       |          |
|  Smoke test      |
|       |          |
| +--Rollback----+ |
| | Replace with | |
| | backup       | |
| +--------------+ |
+------------------+
```

Would a roll back inside the service tag cause the database tag to execute it's rollback? Do rollbacks cascade across sequences?

I haven't had time to set this up yet and test so I thought I'd ask the question instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It appears I was wrong... faulty memory and all that. Rollbacks work across tag boundaries.

I generally recommend against using rollback blocks, since their behavior is generally backwards, unpredictable, and not immediately obvious. The current best practice is actually  to not use agent-based releases at all, as they will not be portable to the forthcoming Release Management Service.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling that would be the case. On the vNext / agent issues I think we're still sitting it out until vNext matures a bit.

Comment: Hey Daniel, rollbacks work across boundaries. If a failure happens in the service block, the database bag and web tag rollbacks will be executed.

Comment: Moreover, I agree that rollbacks are "generally backwards and not immediately obvious", but they are totally predictable.

Comment: @joerage Thanks for the correction. I would have sworn it worked the way I described! That's what I get for not re-testing and validating! :)

Comment: Agent-based releases are as good as vNext releases as neither of them will be portable to RMS on VSO. Check here for more info: http://bit.ly/1EVasR3

Comment: @joerage DSC/PowerShell scripts will be portable with minimal rework.

Comment: You are right @Daniel Mann. However, vNext releases do not enforce the use of DSC. Any Powershell script can be used (and I would guess is mostly used). And anything that is used in Agent-based releases (if not already Powershell) can be easily wrapped within a Powershell script. Don't you think?

Comment: Okay folks that makes my life a bit easier,  I will go and test this out and report back later.

Answer (score 1):

By accident I've managed to test this out with a suitable release and roll back does roll back across the tags as @joerage says.